# Attempt() method is undefined in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to authenticate admin in Laravel project. my **auth.php** as shown below:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
```

**AdminController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    
    
    public function adminLogin(){
        return view('auth.adminLogin');
    }



    public function cheackAdminLogin(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);
if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email,
               'password' => $request->password])) {

             return redirect()->intended('/admin');
        }
        
       return back()->withInput($request->only('email')); */
}
    
    }
```

**AdminDashboardController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminDasboardController extends Controller
{
    public function adminPanel()
    {
        return view('adminPanel');
    }
}
```

The problem that I encountered that when I want to check the admin login, the attempt() function when I wrote it, I get an error message in the editor **"Undefined Method"**.
I tried to using auth()->guard('admin')->attempt() instead of Auth::guard('admin')->attempt but the problem is same.
please help

Comment: So it looks like `guard('admin')` is misconfigured and doesn't have an `attempt()` method. Try in `php artisan tinker`: `auth()->guard('web')->attempt()` (should be `false`), vs `auth()->guard('admin')->attempt()` (which throws an error). Also, `auth()` and `Auth::` are different methods that do the same thing :)

Comment: ok, I will do it.

Comment: Sidenote, having different models for Users and Admins is gonna make Authentication difficult. Consider using Roles, where a User is the entity that can login, with different Roles (User, Admin) differentiating their permissions once logged in. Also, include your `Admin.php` Model; I bet it's missing `Authenticatable` as an extension, and the related traits

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem of type hint

```
use Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard;
```

```
/** @var SessionGuard $adminGuard */
$adminGuard = Auth::guard("admin");

if ($adminGuard->attempt($credentials)) {
...
```